# When starting my app in Fastapi, it shows me that I have a failure in the model

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am creating a bookings app and what I want is to store the data at the moment with sqlite and I get this error that I don't quite understand

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./bookings.db"


engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

Models:

```py
class CreateBooking(Base):
    __tablename__= 'CreateBookings'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    phone = Column(Integer,unique=True)
    email = Column(String,unique=True, index=True)
    date  = Column(String)
    time = Column(String)
```

Schemas:

```py
class BookingResponse(BaseModel):
    phone: str
    email: EmailStr
    date : str
```

And this error:

```
fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that sessionmaker(class_='Session', bind=Engine(sqlite:///./bookings.db), autoflush=False, autocommit=False, expire_on_commit=True) is a valid pydantic field type
```

Comment: The error is related to the FastAPI part of your code, not the SQLAlchemy part. The error seems to indicate that you're attempting to use a `sessionmaker` instance as the response model in your view.

Comment: thank you, pass a pydantic model and solved